# Generators of integers under the operation of addition the integers of mod 8

Tags: abstract-algebra

A generator is defined as I believe as the elements of which the entire subgroup can be generated by. With that being the case then wouldn't the generators of the integers under addition consist solely of $1,-1$

For mod $8$ I am thinking the generators would be the prime factors of 8 which are $2, 2^2$? Am I right?

Comment: Have you worked out what, say, $4$ generates?  You get $\{0,4\}$.

Comment: $2^2$ is not prime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For mod 8 the generators are the numbers that do not have prime elements in common with 8. These elements are $\bar{1},\bar{3},\bar{5},\bar{7}$.